# How many times does a for loop evaluate its expression list?

Tags: python, for-loop

I have the following code:

```
list1 = [4,1,2,6]
for elem in sorted(list1):
    #some task
```

I was wondering how many times does Python sort the list using the `sorted()` method? Is it for each iteration or just once?

In other words is the following code more efficient?

```
list1 = [4,1,2,6]
list1 = sorted(list1)
for elem in list1:
    #some task
```

Comment: To format code correctly put 4 spaces before each line

Comment: it sorts it once, why do you think it would sort it more than once?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In both code examples, the list is sorted only once.

The expression on the right of the `in` operator in a for-loop header is evaluated just once, before looping commences. You can read about this in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#for):

> ```
> for_stmt ::=  "for" target_list "in" expression_list ":" suite
>               ["else" ":" suite]
> ```
>
> **The expression list is evaluated once**; it should yield an iterable
>   object.

In fact, the second code example is *less* efficient because there is an unnecessary assignment.